How to symlink a React library within the same repo using Docker
A project has the below partial directory structure:
projectA
├── src
├── projectB
│   ├── package.json
├── package.json
└── Dockerfile

projectB is a directory in which there is another React application. I have been able to successfully symlink the package in projectB with the consumer (projectA) using npm link.
However, I am struggling to replicate this in the Dockerfile, due to the different build contexts. Ultimately, I would like to deploy the application to another environment, where the build steps in the Dockerfile emulate this. My understanding is that Docker doesn't work well with symlinks.
Essentially, what I would like to do is copy the node_modules folder inside projectB to the root of projectA. Any help would be appreciated.
